# What does "fno" stand for in g++'s fno-stack-limit compile option?

Tags: g++

In the following command:

```
$ g++ -fno-stack-limit
```

what does `fno` *stand for*?

Comment: Please stop closing this. It has garnered quite a few views and is, apparently, helpful to others. Yes, you should have read the man page more carefully but that happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's `-f` as "flag" and `no` as "no stack limit"

Comment: The flag description was a bit confusing: *Generate code to ensure that the stack does **not** grow beyond a certain value, either the value of a register or the address of a symbol. (...)*

Comment: @REACHUS: the GCC man page usually uses the same paragraph for `-fdo-foo` and `-fno-do-foo`. What's documented is the `-fdo-foo` in that case, you're supposed to deduce what the opposite would be.